# Como hacer para que no me imprima los espacios en memoria al utilizar ng-for?

Tags: typescript

estoy aprendiendo TypeScript, estoy implementando una función que al accionar un botón me cargue en un html el contenido de un arreglo. Ya logre implementar dicho método pero al momento de accionar el botón me imprime es el espacio en memoria, y yo quiero que me traiga el nombre de las ciudades. A continuación les dejo las clases que tengo definidas y el llamado en el formulario; Agradecería mucho sus respuestas, muchas gracias

A continuación el Modelo:

[image: T]

A continuación el servicio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación el componente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación la definición del html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo quiero que me imprima el nombre de las ciudades.

Comment: Hola, entiendo que por comodidad te veas tentado a usar imágenes. Pero creeme que siempre será preferible el código. Si queremos reproducir tu problema es más fácil hacer `copy/paste` que tener que reescribir todo lo que tienes en las imágenes. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que descripción es un arreglo de objetos, si solo necesitas imprimir la ciudad tendrías que acceder a ella de la siguiente manera `{{opcion.descripcion.label}}`